# how to loop on hrefs?

Tags: javascript, href

I need to get some links from the following code. I managed to reach the `href` of the first one by using:

```js
var link=doc.querySelector('#courses_menu > ul > li:nth-child(2) a');
```

Now I need all these `href`'s. With a loop maybe?

Here is the source I need to work on:

```html
<ul class="tools-menu-ul">
  <li class="tools-menu-back"><a href="#main_menu" class="controls">back</a></li>
     <li><a title="Neural Networks (Elective for MET)" href="Courses/CourseEdition.aspx?crsEdId=109"> CSEN 1005</a></li>

      <li><a title="Systems-on-a-Chip (Elective for MET)" href="Courses/CourseEdition.aspx?crsEdId=111">ELCT 1002 </a></li>

      <li><a title="Seminar on Self Reference" href="Courses/CourseEdition.aspx?crsEdId=115"> CSEN 1009</a></li>

      <li><a title="Seminar on Handheld Augmented Reality" href="Courses/CourseEdition.aspx? crsEdId=120"> DMET 1011 </a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) instead.

```
var links = doc.querySelectorAll('#courses_menu > ul > li a');

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    alert(links[i]);
}
```

Comment: There is a problem, the length of the links is only   1   !?
doesn't that have to do anythign with the nth-child(2) ?

Comment: My mistake, I thought that the selector was fine. I just edited my answer so that it gets all of the links.

Comment: yeah it worked :D 
i did it with ('#courses_menu > ul >li >a );  

Thanks alot